# Jigsaw puzzle solving based on shape C++. OPENCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

color image here : [color_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36VNs.jpg) ploy approximation image here : [poly_approximation_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1KrA.jpg) \n

I got 54 pieces of Jigsaw puzzle, I would like to solve these puzzle using shape of each puzzle.

What I have done is :

1. segment each piece from the background.
2. get the canny edges and the contours.
3. apply poly approximation.

Now, I would like to apply convex hull, but however, I don't know how can I get convex and concave of each piece using opencv.

```
puzzle.input_image.copyTo(input_copy);
cvtColor(puzzle.input_image,input_image_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);   // convert to gray.
Mat thresholded_image=puzzle.get_thresholded_image(input_image_gray);
imshow("thresholded",thresholded_image);
Mat floodfill_image=puzzle.floodfill(thresholded_image);
contours=puzzle.get_contours(floodfill_image);
puzzle.get_puzzle_pieces(thresholded_image,input_copy);

for(int i=0; i< puzzle.pieces_color.size() ; i++){
    Mat temp = Mat::zeros(puzzle.pieces_color.at(i).rows,puzzle.pieces_color.at(i).cols,CV_8U);
    Mat temp2= Mat::zeros(puzzle.pieces_color.at(i).rows,puzzle.pieces_color.at(i).cols,CV_8U);
    Mat temp3= Mat::zeros(puzzle.pieces_color.at(i).rows,puzzle.pieces_color.at(i).cols,CV_8U);
    cvtColor(puzzle.pieces_color[i],temp,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    temp2=puzzle.get_thresholded_image(temp);
    puzzle.pieces_binary.push_back(temp2);
    temp3=puzzle.get_canny(temp2);
    imshow("temp2",temp3);
    imwrite("temp2.jpg",temp3);
    // getting the contours. 
    contours=puzzle.get_contours(temp2);
    for(int c=0; c< contours.size() ; c++){     // poly approxamiation for all the contours for every piece. 
            std::vector<cv::Point> poly;
            cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[c]),poly,5,true); 
             // Iterate over each segment and draw it
            std::vector<cv::Point>::const_iterator itp= poly.begin();
             while (itp!=(poly.end()-1)) {
            cv::line(temp2,*itp,*(itp+1),cv::Scalar(255),2);
                 ++itp;
        }
        // last point linked to first point
         cv::line(temp2,*(poly.begin()),*(poly.end()-1),cv::Scalar(255),2);
    }
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Some images and a piece of code might help to get quicker answers ...

Comment: @tfv images, and code have been added. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What exactly do you hope to achieve by using convex hull ?

Comment: with convex hull, I'm assuming that I can measure how deep the concave, or how tall the convex of the puzzles. So I can match one side of the puzzle with concave with the other puzzle side with convex.  @MidhunHarikumar